# Provide 4 possible outcomes of the following program

Tags: c, multithreading

Consider the following program with 2 threads

Lock.lock = new Lock()

::Thread 1::

```
while(true){
   print("Red");
   print("Red");
   lock.unlock();
}
```

::Thread 2::

```
while(true){
   lock. lock()
   print("Blue");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean outcomes? With what you've provided, the program will execute forever.

Comment: There's actually only one, syntax error.

Comment: Possibility 1: if you don't do your own work, you'll fail your course.

Comment: To expand on George's answer - the program won't run, it will fail during compilation with a syntax error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since the `while(true)` loops will go on indefinitely there are infinitely many outcomes... but here are a couple nonetheless:

Option 1:

- Red Red Blue Blue...

Option 2:

- Red Blue Red Blue...

Option 3:

- Blue Red Red Red...

Option 4:

- Red Red Red Red...

Option 5:

- Blue Blue Red Red...

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes..?

Comment: Not the dv, but even if we pretend the code is compilable, it says to display 4 possible outcomes, it doesn't imply that 4 includes every possible outcome.

Comment: Thanks, think I can accept Dove Devic's answer.

Comment: Ah okay, well I will edit that then accordingly @George. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again, seems it has more than four answers. :-)